# Calling parent component function from angular 4 material dialog

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I have a working function (say **functionA**) in my parent component. 
However, I want to make it nicer by adding Angular Material dialog which basically contains 'Yes' and 'No' button. Clicking 'No' will close the dialog which is working fine. Now if I click 'Yes', I want it to call '**functionA**'.
How to do so with Angular 4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's all in the documentation, that you probably haven't read :

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent);

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  this.functionA();
});
```

In your modal, the button should be

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
```

This will return true in the subscribe.

Comment: I tried to set the 'No' with false but it also triggered functionA. Any idea why this happening?

Comment: Because there's no condition in your call ? Just add `if (result)` before your call ...